# Jobe Server - Error while creating new server - Moodle - Code Runner

Tags: moodle, coderunner

Tried to deploy an standalone jobe server as a backend service, with the CodeRunner plugin in moodle programming assessment.

It is giving the following mapping error.

[[image: question error]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99IXD.png)
    Jobe Successful
[[image: Jobe running successfully]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCrT.png)

[image: request response error message]

Answer (score 0):

Since your Jobe sandbox clearly has C on it and you're not getting an error saying the Jobe sandbox is down, the most likely explanation is that the checkbox "Enable Jobe sandbox" is unchecked in the administrator's CodeRunner settings page.

Comment: Tried to setup new Jobe Server, Getting the above response. Before consuming it to Moodle Account.

Comment: It's very hard to read the image. But it looks like it's probably a run of *testsubmit.py* and that you're getting an error 'Can't assign requested address' when opening a socket to localhost. This suggests a broken Linux install. What sort of Linux install do you have? You could try changing the Python variable JOBE_SERVER (line 51) from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' . If that fixes it your /etc/hosts file is likely broken.

What output do you get from the terminal commands

#wget localhost

and

Comment: Timed out on editing ... try the command `ping localhost` and tell me what you get.